# Error in chaining multiple conditions inside a single if statement

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, string

I am working on a shell script and a part of the script should check if a file doesn't exist or if the filename provided is null (i.e. no filename has been provided).

Here is my code -

```
if ! [[ -e "$file_name" ] ||  [[ -z "$file_name" ]]  ; then
    echo "File doesn't exist"
    exit 2
else
    echo "ok"
fi
```

On running this script, this snippet is giving me syntax errors or running the else code when it should run the code inside the if statement.

I know that my code does have some syntax issues ( and the logic doesn't look too good either ? ).

I tried to research more about this, but, I just cannot seem to find a good resource that covers everything that I needed for this.

There's already a lot of questions on this, but the problem is that I am not sure how to use a not operator in one of these conditions.

So what do I change?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a typo in your code, where you have `]` instead of `]]` to close the first `[[...]]` construct:

Try:

```
if [[ -z "$file_name" || ! -e "$file_name" ]]; then
    echo>&2 "File doesn't exist"
    exit 2
else
    echo ok
fi
```

Which is ksh syntax (also supported by a few other shells now including bash) or:

```
if [ -z "$file_name" ] || [ ! -e "$file_name" ]; then
    echo>&2 "File doesn't exist"
    exit 2
else
    echo ok
fi
```

Which is standard `sh` + `[` syntax.

Both the `[` utility and the `[[...]]` conditional construct of the Korn shell, understand `!` as a negation operator in their respective test expressions, but you could also use the `!` shell operator:

```
if [ -z "$file_name" ] || ! [ -e "$file_name" ]; then
    echo>&2 "File doesn't exist"
    exit 2
else
    echo ok
fi
```

The `[[...]]` construct also has its own `||` operator. But you can also use the `||` shell operator in between two `[[...]]` invocations or the `!` shell operator instead of the `!` conditional expression operator like in your approach:

```
if [[ -z "$file_name" ]] || ! [[ -e "$file_name" ]]; then
    echo>&2 "File doesn't exist"
    exit 2
else
    echo ok
fi
```

The `[` utility also has `-o` as a *or* operator but that operator is deprecated and should not be used as it makes for unreliable test expressions. For instance <strike>`[ -z "$file_name" -o ! -e "$file_name" ]`</strike> fails with a `too many arguments` error with the `[` builtin of the `bash` shell when `file_name='='`.

Note that even though that doesn't change the logic, I've moved the `-z` check first as it's a less expensive one since it doesn't involve any query to the system. I've replace the first `echo` with `echo>&2` for that error message to be sent to stderr instead of stdout.

Comment: This is probably the answer. 

And I am using bash.

But when I am running that snippet (I have edited the question, please have a look), it's not working for the file not found case. It's working for the case when the filename is empty.

Comment: @hmm-m-m it doesn't look like your question has been updated at this point, https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/749722/revisions shows only one revision

Comment: Yes! 
I was going to modify the question after replying here, but I am getting - "Your post cannot be submitted at this time due to the volume of spam and abuse originating from your network. We apologize for any inconvenience. See the help center for more." when I try to post it .

Comment: I'll post it as soon as possible. I have no idea why this is happening, I literally made this account today.

Comment: @hmm-m-m change the `&&` to `||` and it should work as expected.

Comment: Yup it worked. Really silly mistake lol